# reading BLOB_TYPE field

Tags: sql, rstudio, firebird

I have a field called *Observation* where information is stored in BLOB SUB_TYPE. How can I make an SQL SELECT to be able to read it?

Comment: What language are you trying to read from? In JDBC is pretty simple.

Comment: How can I know which language ?

Comment: You are reading the blob column using... Java... or C#... or Kotlin... using the command line... something else? which one?

Comment: I am using R studio  to view the columns but the observation field only shows something like as.raw(c(0x4e, 0x6f, 0x76, 0x61, 0x20, 0x54, 0x61, 0x62

Comment: Ah, OK. That's a "feature" of R Studio. The data is still in the database, but R Studio shows it that way. You would need to use a different tool, or even write some code in a programming language to retrieve it. Does R Studio have something like a "right-click -> Save as..."? If not, then use a different tool.

Comment: No, I don´t think R studio have something like this...I thought it was possible to write a SQL statement to be able to read that column...

Comment: First of all, there is no `BLOB SUBTYPE` type. There is `BLOB` datatype which has subtypes `SUBTYPE 0`, `SUBTYPE 1` and so forth. Hence, `BLOB SUBTYPE` without the very subtype is just meaningless broken declaration. Second, if the data in those columns is small you can try to cast it `SELECT CAST (BLOBCOLUMN AS VARCHAR(8192)) FROM ...`

Comment: See https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-bnrytypes.html and https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-conversion.html You may try to convert binary blob to text blob, but I can only wonder if it would work. Binary blobs were not intended to have human-readable data anyway

Comment: @Arioch'The It is also entirely possible the value from the comments is just the blob-id, and not the contents of the blob.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the specific data he quoted seems to be just plain text. http://www.asciitable.com/ `Nova Tab` Granted, the same column in just the next row may hold whatever any random data.